# Create multiple charts in one xtrareport

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport, xtrachart

I have the following chart that displays 3 patient tests.

[image: A chart with 3 legends]

As you see all the tests(Legends) are displayed in a single chart
How do I make the report create a chart for each test(Legend).
I know its ingenious to create multiple charts manually in the report and assign DataSource and DataMember for each of them because the number of tests(Legends) is dynamic it maybe 2,3,4 or any number, so there may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of using Sub Reports to display the three reports? you can pass the parameters that the user selected to the Sub Reports. This gives the ability of having different data sources for each Sub Report as well as having your own data source for your main report

Answer (score 0):

Use the XRChart data filtering functionality to filter the Series data according to the current Test value (see the [Use Charts to Visualize Data in Report Groups](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/3291/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/use-report-controls/use-charts-and-pivot-grids/use-charts-to-visualize-data-in-report-groups) example).